# Reg Expr formatting remove punctuation in mobile number

Tags: regex, replace

I have a huge file with strings looking like this :

```
ABS; Ba; Accountant / Belastingconsulent;Nederlands;2001/04/03;2001/04/03;Hollestraat 32a 9450 HAALTERT;straat xxa;9450;HALTER;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (53) 12.34.56;;Beekstraat 67/1 9300 AALST;Beekstraat 67/1;9300;AALST;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (474) 12.34.56;;
1;emailaddr@email.com; deepurllink;
```

The number fields are in a non-useable format now :

```
;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (53) 12.34.56;;Somestraat 67/1 9300 AALST;Somestraat 67/1;9300;AALST;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (474) 12.34.56;;
```

I need to find at least the mobile number and have it formatted from :

```
;+32 (474) 12.34.56;
```

to

```
;+32474123456;
```

If anyone could suggest a reg expr to find and replace this, I would be grateful.

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to guess.. here is info that will help you:

RegExp:       `/;(\+[0-9]{2}) \(([0-9]{2,3})\) ([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})/g`

pattern:      `;(\+[0-9]{2}) \(([0-9]{2,3})\) ([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})`

replace with:  `;$1$2$3$4$5`

Here we capture 5 groups:

```
group 1: (\+[0-9]{2})
group 2: ([0-9]{2})
group 3: ([0-9]{2})
group 4: ([0-9]{2})
group 5: ([0-9]{2})
```

Input:

```
ABS; Ba; Accountant / Belastingconsulent;Nederlands;2001/04/03;2001/04/03;Hollestraat 32a 9450 HAALTERT;straat xxa;9450;HALTER;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (53) 12.34.56;;Beekstraat 67/1 9300 AALST;Beekstraat 67/1;9300;AALST;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (53) 12.34.56;+32 (474) 12.34.56;;1;emailaddr@email.com; deepurllink
```

Output:

```
ABS; Ba; Accountant / Belastingconsulent;Nederlands;2001/04/03;2001/04/03;Hollestraat 32a 9450 HAALTERT;straat xxa;9450;HALTER;+3253123456;+3253123456;;Beekstraat 67/1 9300 AALST;Beekstraat 67/1;9300;AALST;+3253123456;+3253123456;+32474123456;;1;emailaddr@email.com; deepurllink
```

Answer (score -1):

For `;+32 (474) 12.34.56;` to become `;+32474123456;`, find `/[.() ]/g` and replace by nothing.

Comment: And what if other text contains `()`. in your case u r going to replace all backspace as well

Comment: I know, but I just answer his question of formatting the number from `;+32 (474) 12.34.56;` to `;+32474123456;`